# What's the difference between GetModuleHandle(NULL) and AfxGetInstanceHandle() functions?

Tags: function, winapi, difference

What's the difference between win32api GetModuleHandle(NULL) and AfxGetInstanceHandle() functions?

Comment: `AfxGetInstanceHandle` uses per-module state to retrieve the appropriate `HMODULE`. When used inside a DLL it will return the appropriate `HMODULE` to used when loading resources from that DLL, for example. `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` will always return the `HMODULE` of the executable image used to start the process.

Comment: Also AfxGetInstanceHandle is not WINAPI but MFC function.

Comment: @IInspectable , what is the "per-module state" mean ? the state (image) of executed dll or exe i guess? If so, when im using AfxGetInstanceHandle  in the exe, it must return HMODULE of the exe or dll, from where the function was executed? Right?

Comment: MFC stores certain state information. It stores *per-module* state, *per-thread* state, etc. The details are documented at [TN058: MFC Module State Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ft1t4bbc.aspx). It's a long read. Sorry, no short-cuts. MFC is hard to learn by itself. Not knowing the Windows API doesn't help much.